# Print TTY Stream to Terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, serial, tty

I have a usb device. The driver for said devices sets up a ttyUSB0 stream for interfacing with the device. I am trying to understand how the data from this device is formatted. Is it possible to display that stream, live, on my terminal (something like piping to stdout)?

This device is running on a limited embedded system. The system uses a Linux 2.6 kernel and busybox shell, so I can't simply install applications like a serial terminal, and many cli programs which are default on most distros (such as `screen`) aren't available on my system.

Comment: Which device and which driver?

Comment: it's an [aeon z-wave controller](http://aeotec.com/z-wave-usb-stick) and the driver is a generic [cp210x chipset USB to UART kernel module](http://www.silabs.com/products/mcu/pages/usbtouartbridgevcpdrivers.aspx) for linux 2.6.

Comment: I'll take a look.  Have you tried `cat /dev/ttyUSB0`?

Comment: Protocol details seem to be locked up.  Is it line-oriented (like HTTP) or are there lots of raw binary values to send?

Comment: @cxw hello. thank you for the help. i've come to the same conclusion about protocol details, and i am exploring a different option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woodrow, makes sense.  In case anyone else reads this question, a general answer-

Use `stty` to set baud rate and stop bits to match the z-wave.
Use `echo -ne` to output binary values.
Use `cat` or `read` to read input if it is text-like.
See http://www.busybox.net/BusyBox.html for details.  It is probably easier to write a small C program that understands the protocol than to try to use the shell.  Good luck!